# Preventing a Button Press From Registering TKInter/Python 3.3

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm in the process of creating a filling program with Python 3.3/Tkinter and have run into an issue that's really stumping me. Basically, I want to prevent button presses from registering while certain processes are taking place. I tried changing the button's state to `state='disabled'` but this only delays the click from registering until after the function is finished running. In other words, despite the button being "disabled", if it's clicked, the button press will register as soon as it's re-enabled.  Please see the example code below.

```
def Button_Action:
    Button.config(state='disabled')
    #Activate some hardware that takes a few seconds.
    Button.config(state='normal')
```

So, the question is: How can one selectively ignore button presses in Tkinter/Python 3?

I'm really new to Python and have tried searching for relevant questions to no avail, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question, or has been asked before. Also, I have tested this with both `Radiobutton`s as well as, standard `Button`s (in case that helps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`update`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method) method.

```
def button_action():
    b.config(state='disabled')
    b.update() # <----------
    # Activate some hardware that takes a few seconds.
    b.update() # <----------
    b.config(state='normal')
```

The first call to `update` is to make the button displayed as disabled state.

The second call to `update` is to handle all pending event (clicks in your case) before enable the button.

BTW, it's `normal` state, not `enabled` that make the button back to normal state.

Comment: Hi @Falsetru, thanks for the quick response! I'll test your suggestion out in a bit. Also, thanks for catching that typo! (I probably shouldn't ask questions around midnight.) :)

Comment: @Elle, You're welcome. Here's minimal example that show the effect of `update` in your situation: http://pastebin.com/GmUuHP7m . Try it with/without `update` .

Comment: Hi @Falsetru, thanks again for your help, I just accepted this as the answer. (Also, sorry for the delay, I've been absurdly busy.) One quick question though: in your answer, you are using `update()`, but in the PasteBin example you are using `update_idletasks()`. Is there reason for this? Should I use one over the other in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @Elle, If you follow the link in the answer, you can find more about `update`, `update_idletasks`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can unmap the button from its master. Depending on what function you used to pack the button into its master, which can be a tkinter window or a tkinter widget, you can either use `pack_forget()`, `grid_forget()` or `place_forget()` for `Button.pack()`, `Button.grid()` or `Button.place()` respectively, as the first line of the button's callback function. You can again remap the widget back into its master by calling `Button.pack()`, `Button.grid()` or `Button.place()` depending on what you had used previously, in the last line of the callback function.

Example:

```
def Button_Action:
    Button.pack_forget()
    #Activate some hardware that takes a few seconds.
    Button.pack()
```